# Git branch overwrites master when merging without offering conflicts

Tags: php, git, github, version-control, merge

I have master project and one branch made from it. When I merge master with branch, code in branch overwrites the one in master, and I would like to insert only different code from branch in master, or at least to be asked which code I want to keep. Here is one simple example of how I set up everything:

`mkdir project`
`cd project`
`git init`

inside project directory I have one file called index.php with this code:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is master code.
 */
class ClassName extends AnotherClass
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        // this is from master
    }
}
```

Then I make branch:

`git checkout -b my_branch`

And I put this code inside index.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is branch code.
 */
class ClassName extends AnotherClass
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        // this is from branch
    }
}
```

Then I checkout to master and try to merge:

`git checkout master`
`git merge my_branch`

And then branch code will override the one from master. In my master I will have same code like in branch. Shouldn't git offer me to chose which code to keep, or is there any way to force that ? If not, what I am doing wrong ?

If I make this change in branch code:

`class ClassName extends AnotherClass => class ClassName extends MyClass`

Then git would do recursive strategy merge, and would take `MyClass` from branch and keep everything else from master.

I do not know if I am showing you good examples, let me try to explain the situation once again:

1) I have some code in `master` that do not exists in `branch`.
2) I have some code in `branch` that do not exists in `master`.

How should I deal with this and not lose that different codes in both master and branch ? If that can not happen on some clean, good planned way, can I at least force git to ask me what I want to do with those differences ? I can only mange to make branch override master, and that is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging a branch means that you want to `add` the `changes` suggested by the branch. You can **NOT** selectively merge a branch. It get's merged as a whole.

To see what is the diff b/w two branches for reviewing before merging, run

`git diff master my_branch`

If you don't feel like the code in the `my_branch` is up to your standards OR is errorenous, don't merge it.

Comment: Thanks I will try with diff

Comment: @offline you can accept it if it answers our question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, then you are checking out `branch`, replacing some of the code from `master`, and then merging `branch` into `master`.

The whole point of making a branch is so that you can make changes to code, and then merge those changes in.

Maybe an example will help.

Let's say you had a file on `master` that only had the content

```
This is good code
```

And then you checked out `branch` and changed the file to say

```
This is great code
```

Now, you checkout `master` again. Right now, the file is

```
This is good code
```

If you merge, then the file will change to

```
This is great code
```

However, if, before merging, you changed the file to say

```
This is really amazing code
```

And then tried to merge, then git would tell you that there was a conflict, and would not automatically merge these files.

[This](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) might help you to get the concept. Basically, because `master` had not changed at all since `branch` was created, git can assume that any changes you made were on purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Well the problem was that people made changes in master while other worked on branch. Is it a good way to solve this by trying to push all new code from master in branch ? Then there would not be a problem, right ?

Comment: right. and if 2 people have changed the code on the same line, it will ask you which one to keep, just like you wanted.

Comment: What would you suggest to me as a good way of pulling changes from master to branch w/o losing new code in branch: `git merge origin/master`, or `git fetch`+ `git rebase origin/master`, or doing that manually ?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you create `branch` from `master`, and then edit both `branch` and `master` in the same places in the code, then there will be a conflict, and you will have to choose which code to keep. This happens by default, and you don't have to do anything special. It's only when you change `branch` without changing `master` that `master` will be overwritten.