# git merge branch to master branch - how to prevent stuff from branch overwritting master branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

currently im facing some problem with git merge where i needed to merge a `branch` into `master` branch, but the process simply overwrite the stuff in `master` from `branch` without prompting to resolve conflict.

*The `branch` was created from `master`, and all the changes are made in `branch` while `master` left untouched all this time. [Or refer the graph i made here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Z9n.png), i want the merged code become `//FOOBAR` not `//BAR`. What should i do so that git can let me manually resolve the conflict?

I also found this thread that probably share the same problem with me but sadly doesn't offer any solution. The last comment seems to describing the problem i faced but sadly do not offer any workaround.

[Git branch overwrites master when merging without offering conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549808/git-branch-overwrites-master-when-merging-without-offering-conflicts)

appreciate all the help and support given and pardon my poor english, thanks.

Comment: The changes on the new branch will be applied onto master when you run `git merge`. Could you please give a specific code example that describes your case?

Comment: @Nirupa i tried all the merge strategy, but none produce the result i desired

Comment: @ElpieKay for example the code in `master` is `//foo`, while in `branch` is `//bar`, i want git to be able to prompt to resolve conflict when merging `branch` to `master` and allow me to edit the code to `//foobar`. But git merge simply produce `//bar` without prompting.

Comment: @ChinKk Did you change //foo to //bar in the new branch before the merge?

Comment: @ElpieKay yes, i change the code in `branch` after branching out of `master`

Comment: @ChinKk This is how `git merge` works in your case. If you want the final result to be //foobar, you need to change //foo to //foobar in the new branch instead of //bar. I guess you may misunderstand what `git merge` can do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct merge strategy - probably 'ours'. For more details see GIT documentation,
See: https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies and
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge